# Handling C char arrays with Java char arrays

Tags: java, c, sockets

Through a socket I am sending information from a program written in C to a program written in Java.

Through the program in C, I am sending two bytes through a char array (using an internet socket), and the received information in Java is stored in a char array also.

My main problem is that the received information in the Java array does not correspond properly to the transmitted information from the C program.

I have read that the chars in Java are 16 bits long, and the chars in C are 8 bits long. That may be the problem, but I do not know how to handle/solve that.

The C code to send information is the following:

```
char buffer[256];
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(fd, buffer, 255);  // getting info from an uart port, which works properly
n = write(sockfd,buffer,3); // send the information through the socket
```

Part of the Java code (for an Android app) is the following:

```
char[] buffer = new char[256];
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
int readX = in.read(buffer, 0, 3);
if (readX > 0) { // I am using a handler to manipulate the info
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.obj = buffer;
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
} 
....
// Part of the handler is the following:
mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            char[] buffer;
            buffer = (char[])msg.obj; // the information here is different from the one sent from the C program
            ....
    }
}
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance, Gus.

Comment: If you can isolate a "minimal case" that fails in the same way, presenting the C source and the Java source, it would (possibly) help.

Comment: There could be lots of ways in which your code gets this wrong. I concur with Vatine that seeing the code would help us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C and C++ the `char` data type is 8-bit characters, corresponding roughly to the Java `byte` type.  In Java, the fundamental `char` type is a 16-bit Unicode character.  When you convert from bytes to characters (or vice-versa) in Java, a mapping has to occur, depending on the character encoding of the byte stream (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, etc), so you have to know how the C byte stream is encoded.  In your case I'd guess it's ISO-8859-1.  If it's really binary data, then you should use the Java `byte` type.

EDIT:

You have to know whether the data being sent from C is character or binary, and if character, how the C program is encoding the data (ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, etc).

If the data is binary then you must use `BufferedInputStream` to read bytes, not `BufferedReader`, which decodes bytes into characters, which you don't want since the data is binary.

If the data is character, then you can use the 2-argument constructor

```
InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charSetName)
```

or one of the other 2-arg constructors that let you specify how to decode bytes into characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem doing so is that the function read from the class BufferedReader does not accept a byte type as argument. About the conversion you mentioned, can you provide any code to do that in Java?, or another alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, with the info you provided for byte transmission through socket I solved the problem I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Java `byte` type, which is an 8-bit signed integer. Also ensure that your `char` type in C is actually 8 bits. The [Boost StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) facility can be used to ensure that.