# How to handle C char array in Java

Tags: java, c, client-server, httpclient

I have a problem realizing a C client/Java server. I have a problem with the put method in server side. My problem is the same as ([Handling C char arrays with Java char arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256373/handling-c-char-arrays-with-java-char-arrays)) but the given solution doesn't work in my case.

My problem is that I receive a corrupt file.

When I see the raw of the original file and the received file i noticed that Java doesn't recognize some character. For example in the original file I have the character represented  by 89 in the received file I have 'ef bf bd' if I write the byte array in UTF-8 or '3f' if I write it in US-ASCII encoding. Here's the important part of my program :

```
InputStream entreeSocket = socketService.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
while(length > 0){
int nb;
if(length > buffer.length)
        nb = socket.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
else
    nb = socket.read(buffer,0,length);
out.write(buffer,0,nb);
if(nb == -1) break;
length -=nb;            
}

out.close();
socket.close();
```

Client side :

```
char buffer[1024];
while(length > 0 ){ 
   nb = read(fd,buffer,1024);
   write(sockfd,buffer,nbChar);               
   length = length - nb;;
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [How to write a UTF-8 file with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java)

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Is this a job for JNI?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with JNI

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a client server and you use socket programming it would be good to use hton() and ntoh() functions just to be sure. These are functions that are used in C/C++ and I am sure that there will be something like this in java. I think it will solve your problem, or at least it is a better implementation. I give you the link :

http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html

I find the description below the functions very informative.